# Get window state change notifications from another pocess

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I would like to know when a window in another program (that I don't have access to the source of) is moved, minimized, closed, etc. I have the HWND of the Window in the other process. I can get the process/thread IDs. I know about monitoring my own process's WndProc. But I can't figure out how to cleanly monitor the other process's WndProc.

Thoughts so far (haven't tried them though):

1. Polling - just grab the window state periodically from my process. This is fairly straight-forward but is 'ugly'.
2. SetWindowsHookEx(WM_CALLWNDPROCRET) - hook the other process's WndProc, however I believe this means that I need to inject a DLL into that process with a method that then uses some form of interprocess communication (WM_COPYDATA to send actual data, or something like a mutex to just inform the other process something has changed).

The second one would be "cleaner" than the first, but is definitely more complicated, especially since the rest of the project is in C# and I don't think I can inject a C# DLL into a native application.

Are there other ways not covered above? Would method #1 not be all that bad? WOuld method #2 be less complicated then am I thinking?

Comment: You can also try using UI Automation library, although it may not have support for all the events you may be after: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684021(v=vs.85).aspx In particular you can search for the other application's window by name and then use the Window and Transform control patterns to manipulate it or listen to its events.

Comment: Sounds promising! All I need is minimize, move, and resize. Looking through it briefly, you can subscribe to events. I would want UIA_AutomationPropertyChangedEventId, for which there are UIA_IsOffscreenPropertyId and UIA_BoundingRectanglePropertyId for minimized and move/resize. However they do warn that not all windows play nicely with this API. There is even a .NET library of it (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748252(v=vs.110).aspx).  Can you write up an answer that shows how to go from a HWND (preferred, there can be multiple windows with the same name) to getting events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample that should get you started:

```
AutomationElement windowElement = AutomationElement.FromHandle(WindowHandle);
if(windowElement != null)
{
            System.Windows.Automation.Automation.AddAutomationPropertyChangedEventHandler(
                    windowElement,
                    System.Windows.Automation.TreeScope.Element, this.handlePropertyChange,
                    System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement.BoundingRectangleProperty);
}

    private void handlePropertyChange(object src, System.Windows.Automation.AutomationPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Property == System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement.BoundingRectangleProperty)
        {
            System.Windows.Rect rectangle = e.NewValue as System.Windows.Rect; 
            //Do other stuff here
        }
    }
```

You should probably call System.Windows.Automation.Automation.RemoveAllEventHandlers after you're done listening to the window's events. 
This is just a very basic sample of course. Guy Barker seems to be the best authority on this library and has provided quite a few samples. He suggests using the native version instead of the managed one but each version has its drawbacks. For your purposes it seems the Managed version should do.

Comment: Thanks! It is working great. I am getting all the bounding box updates. However no minimization notifications (even after adding IsOffscreenProperty), however I do get rectangle changes during minimization (to -32000,-32000) so that is good enough. Thanks for introducing me to the automation library!

Comment: You can probably use this for getting minimize:               `System.Windows.Automation.Automation.AddAutomationPropertyChangedEventHandler(
                        windowElement,
                        System.Windows.Automation.TreeScope.Element, this.handlePropertyChange,
                        System.Windows.Automation.WindowPattern.WindowVisualStateProperty); ` And check if e.NewValue = Minimized

Comment: Yup! Just found that one and tested it, works great! I am now looking for Z-order. Unsure if it is at all possible. I think it would be UIA_PositionInSetPropertyId in the native interface, but can't find the equivalent in managed.

Comment: You can download a utility called AccEvent that comes bundled with the Windows SDK and use it to look at automation events generated by your window

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to this world of UI Automation! I have it from here.

Comment: One last comment, I ended up having to use the "native" way (through the COM library, so almost as easy as the managed way) because the BoundingRectangleProperty were being delayed by seconds (WindowVisualStateProperty however were on-time). Switching over to native fixed this issue.

Comment: Yes there are performance issues with event reception in the managed version, particularly when dealing with WinForms